# date-fns equal to moment(date).format('L')?

Tags: momentjs, date-fns

If I use momentjs like `moment(date).format('L')` it will format date according to the input locale. For example for `US` will output `10/31/2018`.

How can I do the same using date-fns? If I use `format(date, [format], [options])` it will always format date based on the input [format] no matter the locale passed in [options]?

Comment: I fear that this feature is not available on date-fns `v1.29.0`, but it is present in v. 2 (currently `v2.0.0-alpha.25`). With this newer release you will be able to use the `P` token when calling `format` as described [here](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/v2.0.0-alpha.25/CHANGELOG.md#changed).

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks for your note. I will try with the alpha.25 and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

With date fns, you can use Long localized date

[image: Long localized date]

https://date-fns.org/docs/format

For example, equivalent of **moment(date).format('L')** should be **format(new Date(), 'P')**